# Include dygraphs in Jekyll-run site from R

Tags: r, jekyll, r-markdown, dygraphs

Is it possible to include dygraphs chart or some of other js-object supported by htmlwidgets.org to Jekyll-run site from R?

I've tried different variants (Rmd -> Md or Rmd -> html) with no success. The best outcome I have, dyghraphs is included into html-code but doesn't show up on the page (example: http://quantviews.github.io/dygraphs-test/).
Is there any working examples of Jekyll-run site with dygraphs included from Rmd-files?

Comment: You have some assets links to **/libs/** folder that are dead.

Comment: David, you're right! That seems to be the source of the problem with "Rmd -> html" approach. But I can't' understand how to fix it. Local html file shows dygraphs chart without problems and libs links work fine. But when I start Jekyll (whether local or on Github pages) links to libs folder includes folder of the post (i.e. /dygraphs-test/libs and not just /libs). Do you have any suggestions on how to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I think Jekyll is skipping the "libs" directory that's in your _posts folder. (I'm pretty sure it's designed not to process sub directories under "_posts".) The fix is to move the libs folder up and then update the links to point to the new location. For example:

1. Move the "_posts/libs" folder up one directory so it's sitting next to "_posts".
2. Add a "/" to the front of the URLs for all the `<script src="libs/...` links so they call from the docroot. Should look like: `<script src="/libs/...`.
3. Add a "/" to the front of the URLs for all the `<link href="libs/...` links so they call from the docroot. Should look like: `<link href="/libs/....`.

That's it for the main fix. But, there is another bug too. In the `_posts/2015-05-15-dygraphs-test.html` file, there is a call to:

```
<script src="libs/dygraphs-binding-0.4.1/dygraphs.js"></script>
```

But the version 'dygraphs-binding' version in your current libs directory is 0.4.3. I tried just changing the directory name and that worked for me. (i.e. "/libs/dygraphs-binding-0.4.3/dygraphs.js" becomes "libs/dygraphs-binding-0.4.1/dygraphs.js"). It would probably be better to actually line everything up, but that will at least get you working.

Comment: Thank you, Alan! libs folder is created automatically by rmarkdown::render function that I was using to convert Rmd-file to html ("lib_dir" option in front matter). I haven't yet figured out how to move link to libs one "folder up" in front matter but I could it directly in html. The only thing is that changing links to <link href=".../libs/....  not just "/libs" has led to a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

- 1. render with `rmarkdown::html_output`, copy dygraph dependencies from header
- 2. create a new jekyll layout in `_layouts/` with the dygraphs dependencies (changing `libs` to `/libs` as mentioned before)
- 3. run rmarkdown again, this time with `rmarkdown::html_fragment` to generate html without header
- 4. copy html fragment to `_includes/`
- 5. create a new blog post using layout specified in [2]
- 6. include html fragment in body of blog post using `{% include html_fragment.html %}`